# Deploying full stack app to digital ocean not serving the frontend from the express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, digital-ocean

I am deploying my app to digitalOcean using [App Platfrom](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/quickstart/),
My app structure as follow:

```
 client
       ├── /public
       ├── /src
       ├── package-lock.json
       └── package.json

 index.js // this the index of the express server 
 routes
       └── api.js
 package-lock.json
 package.json
```

The client folder is the react app and the root folder is the express server.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/deploy-react-express-app-heroku/) on how to deploy express server that include react app
by serving react files from express server using:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

which included in `index.js` file in root directory.
when i deployed the app to heroku everything was fine as react frontend is been served by the server from client folder and backend api working fine, but i want to deploy it to digitalocean instead,so the important part is defining the scripts in packages.json in root directory which will looks like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "digitalocean-build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
}
```

but as in digitalocean when configure the app before deployment there is two options provided

```
Build Command // i used here npm run digitalocean-build

Run Command  //i used  npm run  start
```

After deployment done when i check the url only the server index is running but not both the server and react frontend.
I have been struggling in this for almost two days and I'm sure there is something I haven't cover it yet. i will really appreciate any help.

Comment: You're using ```npm run build``` inside your digital ocean build command but you haven't defined it.

Comment: @AsadJivani can  you tell me exactly where to define it ? you mean in scripts inside package.json? in digital ocean   build command  im putting `npm run digitalocean-build` which will run this script `cd client && npm install && npm run build` and in deployment logs in can see the build process for both client and server but client no been serving by the server

Comment: Yes, are you using any build pack such as a web pack or a tool like create-react-app ? if you're then you have to define another property in the scripts object like ```"build": "build command"```, if you're able to make the build using digital ocean command which I wonder how, then make sure you're also executing ```npm start``` to serve your express server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as a build command.

```
npm i && npm --prefix frontend install && npm --prefix frontend run build
```